# Body background image does not show in web browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser, background-image

So, I've seen these questions a lot but I've tried all the solutions and have found none of them to work. It's giving me a headache and I can't take it anymore. So my background image is placed as follows:

```
<body background="images/farmancover.jpg"/>
```

It's rather simple, in fact check it out on my website:
http://farmanp-ux.com

Now, my problem is that the background image does not show in any of my web browsers and it's a pain to figure it out. If you guys could gladly help out, it would be much appreciated! I'm a newbie on this so please be gentle.

Comment: You should make the effort of posting your (relevant) code here! Just referencing links will normally get your questions closed!

Comment: Hello user1954122, to have your code show correctly, select it and then use the `{ }` button in the toolbar. Cheers!

Comment: I no I just added it, that was my mistake.

Comment: thanks for helping me out arttronics

Comment: It was indeed added, but it did not show up because it became muted. You need to select it and apply `code` format to it as explained above.

Comment: Also http://www.farmanp-ux.com/images/farmancover.jpg gives a 404 currently

Comment: Agush - that is another issue I have to figure out how to fix, when you go into other parts of the site (designs, contact, other tabs), it should have the image there on the Safari browser.

Comment: Although @arttonics has have fixed your original issue your markup is still [full of errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.farmanp-ux.com%2Ffarman.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and should be fixed to prevent problems in other browsers. As is the solution [fiddle](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FeXKza%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually use the original file of `farmancover.jpg` which is `6.7MB` in size, you need to convert it to an actual `.jpg` file! Even though this filename has extension `.jpg`, it's a **Adobe PSD** project file with wrong extension.

Having said that, it's very odd to have a `.jpg` with that filesize, which is a giveaway that something is the matter.

[image]

---

**First**, ensure you have a valid `.jpg` image file.

The correct filename is [**farmancover.jpg**](http://farmanp-ux.com/images/farmancover.jpg).

It is at this location: http://farmanp-ux.com/images/farmancover.jpg

Your filenames are case sensitive too.

The correct image path then is:

```
'images/farmancover.jpg'
```

To access the folder contents of all your images, use this URL: http://farmanp-ux.com/images/

Then in your CSS Style sheet located here: http://www.farmanp-ux.com/css/style.css

**Change this:**

```css
body
{background-repeat:none}
```

**To this:**

```css
body {
  background:url(http://www.farmanp-ux.com/images/farmancover.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-repeat:none
}
```

Also seen in your CSS Stylesheet is that the last attribute per CSS Selector fails to have a **semicolon**. Please ensure **each** attribute ends with one.

---

**Second**, in your HTML webpage, remove the **EXTRA** `body` tag you have for background image.

**End Result:**

[**jsFiddle DEMO with Background Image**](http://jsfiddle.net/eXKza/1/show/)

---

**EXTRA:** Using an [**Online Tutorial**](http://paulmason.name/item/full-screen-background-image-pure-css-code) to show the background image full screen, even for older non CSS3 browsers like IE8, this method was used in the fiddle below.

[**jsFiddle DEMO with Scalable Background Image**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sf6ST/show/)
*(Remove `/show/` from jsFiddle to access edit page)*

Comment: let me see what happens when I change the file name. I think that is correct and is probably what's going on.

Comment: Just fixed the URL, your original non '1' filename is corrupted.

Comment: image is working fine on Safari but still not on Google Chrome, Firefox, and IE

Comment: Please use image file  `FarmanCover1.jpg` since the other image does not render in other browsers. Thanks.

Comment: the problem about that image is that it is a different image than what I want as the background, so it will not be suitable for the website

Comment: I have discovered the underlining issue. Please see EDIT in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: hey artronics, so now it seems that the main issue now is that the image does not exist, but in order to make it work on my web hosting service (machighway), I have to keep everything lower cased. It's viewable when I check it under my local files, but through the public html, it can't access it.

Comment: Because it's `mimi` filetype is wrong and throws off the browsers rendering mechanism. The image does in fact exist because I downloaded it to my hard drive.

Comment: To fix, please open that .jpg file in Photoshop, or access the original, and you'll need to "Save as .jpg".

Comment: That was right! so far so good but now google chrome shows a different thing going on about it. There is some sort of positioning error.

Comment: EDIT - I think that technical issue is one I have to manually fix; it seems to be an error on all browsers and I think it's because I have to get the image to be fixated. Thanks a lot for your solution! I can't believe that was the main issue.

Comment: I've revised my answer with a couple of things that you have overlooked, so please review again. Thanks.

Comment: **EDIT:** You may wish to have your background image full browser viewport that also scales up or down in size automatically. Please see this [**Online Tutorial**](http://paulmason.name/item/full-screen-background-image-pure-css-code) that shows you how, now that you have the .jpg fixed.

Comment: **EXTRA:** Please see Answer for jsFiddle that is based on Online Tutorial. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
<body style="background:url('images/farmancover.jpg');">
```

Although you would normally add this to your CSS file instead of using an inline style.

```
body {
  background:url('images/farmancover.jpg');
}
```

Specifically for your site, the image may not be showing because your image file is actually 
`images/FarmanCover1.jpg` (note that the URL is case sensitive).

The following should give you the desired effect.

```
<body style="background:url('images/FarmanCover1.jpg') no-repeat;">
```

You also have a number of HTML errors but the following has been tested working

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>
    Farman Pirzada - UX Designer - Harvesting creativity one at a time - Ohio, US
  </title>

  <!-- STYLES -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.farmanp-ux.com/css/style.css" />

  <meta content=
    "Farman Pirzada, UX Designer, CSS, HTML5, Web 2.0, portfolio" />
</head>

<body style="background:url('http://www.farmanp-ux.com/images/farmancover.jpg') no-repeat fixed;">
  <img src="http://www.farmanp-ux.com/images/farmanUX.png" class="center" alt="" />
  <div id="navmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="farman.html">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="design.html">designs</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: else you can give the image in style too

Comment: it still does not open up in other browsers and on google chrome it flipped the background image

Comment: Have you changed your code yet? - I am still seeing `<body background="images/farmancover.jpg"/>`  I just tested in Chrome on a Mac and it looked fine

Comment: I just did, so now that background image will be viewed through Safari. I renamed the file to be case sensitive because my host provider can't use upper cased.

Comment: that didn't seem to make any change

Comment: also, i still keep testing it on the chrome browser and get nothing

Comment: Your HTML had quite a few errors (including an img tag in the head, two body tags and an orphaned style tag.)  Added clean markup to the answer and tested across Safari, Chrome and FF

Comment: Your Chrome issue is due to the image being a Photoshop file with a .jpg extension as arttronics points out.  You are actually getting something, it's just that you cannot see the white farnamUK.png image on a white background but if you scroll down you will see that your links are there.

Comment: I've already **+1** your Answer. Good job for pointing out other issues with the webpage. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. A good tip to pass is that IrfanView automatically checks the MIMI type against file extension upon opening the image. Once I saw the filesize was over 6MB something was up. Thanks for the upvote too :-)

Comment: i agree thanks again for finding that error! I'll be sure to keep that in mind in the future!

Answer (score 3):

CSS property `body { background-image: url('images/farmancover.jpg'); };` seems to be preferred these days over specifying it as part of your HTML.

Comment: Your syntax is slightly off, should be  `background-image: url('images/farmancover.jpg');`